# Set 3 buttons on alert dialog, android?

Tags: android, listview, android-mediaplayer, android-alertdialog

I have a list view previewing a list of songs.
On the onclick of a list item an alert dialog appears asking the user to play or download the song.
The song is played from the url using media player class.

What i want to do is that after the user clicks play button he should also be able to stop the playback.

What i have in my mind is either change the name of the command play to stop after user had pressed play and stop appears to stop playing or if i can add a third button to alert dialog simply to stop it.

Please tell me how can i achieve it?

My list item on click code

```
     list .setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
     public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) 
        {
            songURL=songURL.get(position).toString();

            final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog);
            dialog.setTitle("Downlaod or Play?");
            pImage = (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.playImageView);
            pImage.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    try {
                        MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer();
                        player.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                        player.setDataSource(songURL);
                        player.prepare();
                        player.start();
                        pImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.stop);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        // TODO: handle exception
                    }

                }
            });
            dialog.show();

         }});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a custom dialog is more user friendly and more easy in my opinion.
Just have a play button in the dialog. When pressed change the text to "Stop".
Here is a [simple tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-custom-dialog-example/) on custom dialog to get you going.
Hope this helps.

Comment: well i liked this...it works for me...though i am stuck in problem

Comment: So now i am displaying image for play, stop and download, i have added the code to play on the click of imageitem and change its image to stop image....how to add the player.stop() code on the changed image item

Comment: you can add a boolean flag like boolean bIsPlaying; When play is pressed you set it to true, and when pressed again( meaning stop ) you set to false. You can also use player.isPlaying() method.

Comment: You check the conditions to set the image to play or stop.